# Minimum width of first table column

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Is there any way to have the left, first column to have a minimum width...... like 50%?

I've got a varied amount of separate tables (with different headings so they're separate pieces of data).

Obviously table columns change their width according to how much content is within them... if it needs the extra space then it will take more space from other columns in the same table... that's cool but when theres alot of space and it doesn't need any extra space then its alot tidier if they all just stay the same width... like 50%

http://jsfiddle.net/mqatP/5/

Any idea how to do this without testing in PHP how much content is going inside them and adding different classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was surprised to find out that `min-width` doesn't do the trick. However, after playing with it for a while, I came across this solution:

```
td:first-child {
    width: 40%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be pretty cool. Even width: 50% worked as well. So it keeps them all aligned if theres enough space and uses the space if it has it. I have 3-columns sometimes which screws up those but I doubt they can be fixed without a col-2, col-3 and different styles per.

Comment: Although, if you have text that is too long then it overflows rather than wrapping... but I guess there isn't really a way out of that

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to try this to fix the table width in css

```
    table-layout:fixed;
```

and in JavaScript syntax is: `object.style.tableLayout="fixed"`

Comment: I guess this is the cleanest solution but forces wrapping when there is space that it could use

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
tbody>tr>td:nth-child(1),
tbody>tr>td:nth-child(2),
tbody>tr>td:nth-child(3) { width: 50%; }
```